# I am using Django with uWsgi nginx on vps. But I am getting 502 gateway error. My conf files are

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am using Django with uwsgi and nginx but everytime I am getting bad gateway 502. Please help me out. If you need any more details let me know

I am using emperor for uwsgi here is my ini file

Emporer.ini

```
# /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
[uwsgi]
# This is the directory the emperor will watch for new .ini files
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled

# Set the uid and gid. This could be any user you wish
uid     = www-data
gid     = www-data

# Set the log file path.
# Make sure the log file has the required write
# permissions for the emperor process.
logto   = /var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
```

ss.ini(django app)

```
# /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/grub_club.ini
[uwsgi]
# This should point to your Django project directory
chdir   = /home/ss1/ss/src/

# This should point to your Django wsgi file.
# This usually lives alongside your settings.py file
module  = ss.wsgi:application

# This should point to your python environment
# If you have a virtual environment you like to use,
# specify that here
home    = /home/ss1/pro/

master  = true

# This is the number of cores on your server
processes = 1

# You can either connect using HTTP OR
# you can use unix sockets (recommended)
socket  = /tmp/ss.sock
chmod-socket = 664

# Removes all generated sockets and pids when closed
vacuum  = true

# Log file for this Project.
# Make sure the log file has the required write
# permissions for the emperor process.
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/app/ss.log
```

Here is my nginx location app
nginx/sites-available/ss

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/ss
upstream ss_cluster{
    # This will contain one or more endpoints that uWSGI is listening to
    server unix:///tmp/ss.sock;
}
server {
    server_name     domain.in;
    charset         utf-8;
    #server_name    domain.in;
    #return 301 $scheme://domain.in$request_uri;

    # Configuration to deliver static files
    location ^~ /static/ {
    # This will point to the folder where all the static files reside
    # Same location as Django's STATIC_ROOT
    alias     /home/ss1/src/ss/static/;
    # Sets the HTTP headers for expiration time
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff)$ {
           expires 30d;
    }
    }
    # Configuration to deliver media files
    location ^~ /media/ {
    # This will point to the folder where all the media files reside
    # Same location as Django's MEDIA_ROOT
    alias    /home/ss1/src/ss/media/;
    # Sets the HTTP headers for expiration time
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif){
        expires 365d;
    }
    }
    # All other requests are sent to the Django project
    location / {
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass    ss_cluster;
    }
```

But I am getting 502 Bad Gateway?
Thanks in Advance